# WCF Domain Service & JSON Query Parameters

Tags: json, wcf, frameworks, entity

Is it possible to pass a query parameter like the following to limit results returned by a WCF Domain Service exposing a JSON endpoint?

http://MyDomain.com/MyService-MyName-MyDomainService.svc/JSON/GetData?OrderNumber='12345'

I see documentation all over the place showing OData using query parameters but nothing for JSON endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for jsonp (json with padding) it was made to overcome the cross domain problem with json requests but it lets you pass parameters and it can be implemented in a wcf service

Hope this helps !!